# Asp.net entity saving new value to profile

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I just setup a webforms application without MVC and have added a data field to the AspNetUsers database via migrations.  The new field PrinciplID appears in the database.  I want copy the ID of a new user upon registration into the Principal ID field, but have searched for how to do this with no avail.  Can someone please give me some guidance?  TNX.

Comment: you want to save the ID on two differents servers ? At the same time ?

Comment: Have you updated your Entities model?

Comment: With package manager console I updated the database on the local machine. I am not using 2 different servers. The PrincipalId field that I've added to the AspNetUser database works fine.  I've created the ability for a "Principal" user to create "Associate" users, and when they do the associate user's profile is updated with the Principal user's ID (in the PrincipalID field).  This works fine.  What I'm trying to accomplish is for a new "Principal" user, when registering to have his new ID added to the "PrincipalID" field.  This is needed for some business logic down the road.